# Calling a function passed as an access type that takes no parameters

Tags: ada

Consider a family of functions that take no arguments and return the same type:

```
function Puzzle1 return Answer_Type;
function Puzzle2 return Answer_Type;
function PuzzleN return Answer_Type;
```

I'd like to be able to pass those functions to a subprogram and have the subprogram call the function and use the result. I can pass the function to the subprogram by defining an access type:

```
type Answer_Func_Type is access function return Answer_Type;
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to actually call the passed-in function to get the result:

```
procedure Print_Result(Label    : in String;
                       Func     : in not null Answer_Func_Type;
                       Expected : in Answer_Type) is
   Result : Answer_Type;
begin
   Result := Func;     -- expected type "Answer_Type", found type "Answer_Func_Type"
   Result := Func();   -- invalid syntax for calling a function with no parameters
   -- ...
end Print_Result;
```

Is there a way to do this in Ada without adding a dummy parameter to the functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were trying to use the pointer to a function, not the function itself. Dereference the pointer and all should be well:

```
procedure Main is

   type Answer_Type is new Boolean;

   function Puzzle1 return Answer_Type is
   begin return True;
   end Puzzle1;

   type Answer_Func_Type is access function return Answer_Type;

   procedure Print_Result(Label    : in String;
                          Func     : in not null Answer_Func_Type;
                          Expected : in Answer_Type) is
      Result : Answer_Type;
   begin
      Result := Func.all; -- You have a pointer, so dereference it!
   end Print_Result;

begin

   Print_Result ("AAA",Puzzle1'Access, True);

end Main;
```

Comment: Just to make this explicit: One **must** use `.all` to dereference a function (or procedure) pointer only when the subprogram has no parameters. When there are parameters, as the OP had already encountered, the `.all` is optional.

Comment: @MarcC - Yes good point, i should have mentioned OP was referring to an implicit dereference, which is applied when there are parameters.

Comment: Also, if you want to avoid lots of `func.all` calls, you can rename it locally: `function myfunc return answer_type renames func.all;` and then call `myfunc;`

Comment: Renames can be REALLY convenient.